# sql when i have a table with columns having multiple records

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables one is the `shopping` table and another is the `invoice` table..

now the invoice table has the primarykey column as `pkinvoiceID` and the same key exists in shopping table as `fkinvoiceID`

no the fkinvoiceID can be the same ID for multiple rows having different status like

the shopping table it can contain 3 rows with same `invoiceID` but different Status, i can do an inner join but i want to make sure that it picks the latest record

Comment: Sample data and desired results is always best.  For example, we don't know what Status is or if there is an effective date or identity

Answer (score 0):

All you need is to use a window function like `ROW_NUMBER()` and `PARTITION` by the `invoiceID` ordered by your table's date field like so:

```
WITH CTE_Shopping_Sorted AS
(
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY invoiceID ORDER BY SomeInvoiceDateField DESC) AS SortId -- Generates a unique sequential ID within each group of invoiceIDs
    FROM Shopping
)

SELECT * -- Replace * with your actual column names for best practice
FROM CTE_Shopping_Sorted
WHERE SortId = 1
```

Note: If the date field you use to generate the `SortId` above is not distinct within each `invoiceID` group, then the SQL engine will randomly choose which record wins in a tie. You can add an additional field to uniqify the `ORDER BY` clause to determine tie-breakers.